# return all rows where the column value is a prefix of a given string

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have a **`table`** which one of its **`columns`** is a string (**`varchar`**);

given a string, for example "/a/b/c/d/e/f", find all rows where the column value is a prefix of that string.
So if there are the following rows:

**`id`**,**`stringColum`**

```
1 ,/a/b/c/d
2 ,/e/f/a
3 ,/a/b/c/d/e/
```

so I want to get in the result rows 1 and 3 because both are prefixes of /a/b/c/d/e/f

Comment: `SELECT * 
FROM sourcetable 
WHERE LOCATE(stringColum, '/a/b/c/d/e/f') = 1`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select * from mytable where '/a/b/c/d/e/f' like concat(stringColum, '%')
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f9d7722bd37cdbcfb58d537b419eb4f2)**:

```
id | stringColum
-: | :----------
 1 | /a/b/c/d   
 3 | /a/b/c/d/e/
```

You can also express this with `INSTR()`:

```
select * from mytable where instr('/a/b/c/d/e/f', stringColum) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

With [`INSTR()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_instr) function:

```
select * from tablename where instr('/a/b/c/d/e/f', stringColum) = 1
```